# Making sure the method declaration is inherited

Tags: c++

How can I protect from accidental definition of non-inherited method where inherited definition is intended. I am told there is trick to express it, but nobody can recall it.

Explanation. I have tree of classes: 'Base' <- 'C' <- 'D', below. Base defines pure virtual function. The function gets redefined in C then in D. But the function has very long argument list.

Somewhere along chain of derivation, there is subtle error in the agrglist which makes D:: non-inherited. Program hapily compiles. And the wrong method is called in the run-time.
Is there trick to cause compilation error when method is non-inherited.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void VeryLongFunctionName(int VeryLongArgumentList) = 0;
};
class C : public Base {
public:
    void VeryLongFunctionName(int VeryLongArgumentList) {
        std::cout << "C::\n";
    }
};
class D : public C {
public:
    void VeryLongFunctionNane(int VeryLongArgumentList) { // typo is intentional. It's the point of the question.
        std::cout << "D::\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Base *p = new D;
    p->VeryLongFunctionName(0);
            // the intention is to print D::. But it prints C::.
            // How can we make compiler catch it.       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p->VeryLongFunctionName();` won't even compile.

Comment: @Prasoon: Yes it does. Code was compiled and run prior to posting.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but you need to change the definition in D to ->
int VeryLongFunctionName(in VeryLOngArgumentList){ ..}
You have int VeryLongFunctionNane right now.

Comment: @Prason: What you consider a 'typo' is part of the question. The question is how tomake compiler catch the error. But the code compiles and runs. Please reread explanation if you need.

Comment: @batbat: What you consider a 'typo' is part of the question. The question is how tomake compiler catch the error. But the code compiles and runs. Please reread explanation if you need

Comment: p->VeryLongFunctionName() is an error because you do not pass its argument, int VeryLongArgumentList.

Comment: @Andrei : It does not compile. Check it [here](http://ideone.com/ceeKs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this exact purpose C++0x introduces the `override` member function decorator, as is already implemented in VC++ 2005 and later: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41w3sh1c.aspx

Alternatively, VC++ permits the following (presumably compiler-specific):

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void VeryLongFunctionName(int VeryLongArgumentList) = 0;
};

class C : public Base {
public:
    void Base::VeryLongFunctionName(int VeryLongArgumentList) {
        std::cout << "C::\n";
    }
};

class D : public C {
public:
    void Base::VeryLongFunctionNane(int VeryLongArgumentList) {
    //   ^^^^^^ now causes a compilation error
        std::cout << "D::\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: Bingo. 'override' is it. Pity not in g++ ... yet.

Comment: The Base:: stuff does not compile in g++

Comment: @Andrei : Edited to reflect that the `Base::` stuff is VC++ specific.

Answer (score 4):

not exactly what you asked for, but i've used this form to reduce the chance for human error:

```
class t_very_long_argument_list {
public:
    t_very_long_argument_list(T1& argument1, const T2& argument2);
    /* ... */
    T1& argument1;
    const T2& argument2;
};

int C::VeryLongFunctionName(t_very_long_argument_list& arguments) {
    std::cout << "C::\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have compilation errors -

- `int VeryLongFunctionName(int VeryLongArgumentList)` supposed to return an `int` which none of the method definitions is doing so.
- `int VeryLongFunctionName(int VeryLongArgumentList)` supposed to receive an `int`.

  p->VeryLongFunctionName(); // Error

With these corrected, you should get the expected results. Check results : http://ideone.com/wIpr9

Comment: @Andrei - What is the compiler you are using ? Please make sure that you include the compiler and it's version in the question. Else many users try to give you suggestions compiling the program with the compilers they have.