# Enforcing Correct Virtual Function Definitions in Derived Classes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, virtual-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making sure the method declaration is inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374326/making-sure-the-method-declaration-is-inherited)

Hello, I have difficulty from time to time enforcing the appropriate definitions of virtual member functions in my class hierarchies. If I mis-define a virtual function inheriting from an interface the bug will quickly come to light as I typically cannot instantiate the derived class. However if inherit from say a Base Class (non-abstract) which in turn has inherited from the interface the bugs become more subtle: ie. in the misdefinition (eg. VIsVisible() vs VisVisible() or small changes in parameter types incl const) then I end up defining and calling functions outside the hierarchy when I think I am inside it. Ideally, when I define the function inside the derived class, I want the compiler to flag it if its not consistent with an existing virtual function in the Base Class by introducing some kind of keyword....  how do others manage this issue?
Thanks for your help/ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the override keyword:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void MyFunction() { /*Blah*/ }
};

class Child : Base
{
    virtual void MyFunction() override { /* DoSomething*/ }
};
```

If you change the definition of `Base::MyFunction` you will now get a compile error.

[override documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41w3sh1c.aspx)

Comment: Is `override` a standard C++ feature?

Comment: It will be in the new C++0x feature set, but I believe it's currently only implemented in MS's compiler. The OP doesn't specify what compiler he is using.

Comment: This is all MS extension stuff AFAIK.

Comment: perfect! - thankyou. I am using VC++ so that works great for me. Also, apologies - this was in fact identical to a previous question as ildjarn pointed out (I was using the wrong tags in my database search).

Comment: @sharptooth: it will be in C++0x, after much fights the proposal of having a `[[overrides]]` attribute was *rejected* by Microsoft (basically they made it clear that they would *never* implement it as they had the `override` annotation), so the committee decided to give in and accept `override` and `final` as *virtual specifiers* placed right before the optional *pure specifier* (i.e. `=0`).

Comment: Also note that different compilers provide warnings even if nothing is present if you *hide* a base function --this will not really help with typos in the function name, but it will help with spurious/missing `const` or errors in argument types.